# Finding Eigen value for a 2 x 2 matrix with only variables

Tags: matrices

$A = \left[\begin{array}[c]{rr} a & b\\ c & d\end{array}\right]$

Normally to find the Eigen values of a matrix I would simply find $det(A-λI)$ and equate it to $0$, which in this case gives me $λ^2-(a+d)λ+ad-bc = 0$

With so many variables, how am I supposed to find the Eigen value for this?

Comment: Letters from the beginning of the alphabet are often used to denote _unspecified constants_.  So they are not intended as variables, but as numbers to be used in creating a formula.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the p-q-formula for quadratic equations :

You get

$$\lambda_1 = \frac{a+d}{2} + \sqrt{\frac{a^2+2ad+d^2}{4}+bc-ad}$$

$$\lambda_2 = \frac{a+d}{2} - \sqrt{\frac{a^2+2ad+d^2}{4}+bc-ad}$$

Comment: I'll mention that this is a commonly-presented result in dynamical systems texts and is often written this way.  The "trace" of a 2 x 2 matrix is $ \ \text{Tr} \ A \ = \ a + d \ , $ so we write $$ \lambda_{1,2} \ = \ \frac{ \text{Tr} \ A \ \pm \ \sqrt{(\text{Tr} \ A)^2 \ - \ 4 (\text{det} \ A)}}{2} \ \ . $$